# ¿Como eliminar bits de un entero?

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente problema escolar:

Dados un decimal `n` y una posición `k` retornar el número decimal sin el k-ésimo bit, es decir, si `n=37` y `k=3`, se debe retornar `33`. El problema que es que me condicionaron contestarlo en una sola línea, (El problema original es de **codefights** al parecer, y solo se puede modificar el `return`), no tengo mucha experiencia en manejo de bits y estoy atascado, estoy codificando en C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todo número tiene una representación binaria. Esto creo que lo todos lo sabemos. Si queremos eliminar el bit X tenemos que aplicar una operación AND sobre dicho bit. La forma de conseguir esto es crear una máscara de bits en la que todas las posiciones contienen un `1` salvo la posición a borrar, en la que se encontrará un `0`.

Ejemplo para borrar el 2º bit

```
int numero = 150;
int mask = 0xFFFFFFFD; // 0xD = 1101
int resultado = numero & mask;
std::cout << resultado; // imprime 148
```

Si ahora lo queremos hacer dinámicamente la cosa se complica un poco.

Una ecuación muy útil para cambiar el bit que deseemos es:

```
resultado = numero ^ ((-nuevoValorDelBit ^ numero) & (1 << indiceDelBit));
```

Donde:

- `nuevoValorDelBit` puede valer `0` o `1`.
- `indiceDelBit` es la posición del bit. Recuerda que los índices empiezan en 0.

Llevado esto a nuestro código:

```
int numero = 150;
int bitABorrar = 1; // el 2º bit
int resultado = numero ^ (numero & (1 << bitABorrar));
```

Para entender esta ecuación lo mejor es coger lapiz y papel:

```
numero = 150 = 1001 0110
A = 1 << bitABorrar = 1 << 1 = 0010
B = numero & (1 << bitABorrar) = numero & A = 1001 0110 & 0010 = 0010
C = numero ^ (numero & (1 << bitABorrar)) = numero ^ B = 1001 0110 ^ 0010 = 1001 0100
resultado = C = 1001 0100 = 148
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me dejo claro lo que se tiene que hacer y las operaciones a utilizar, me has sacado de dudas, tengo que estudiar mas de estas operaciones a nivel de bits.

Answer (score 1):

En una sola línea, en realidad no elimina el bit, solo lo pone en cero, se trata de múltiplos de 2.

```
int k=3,n=37; n-=k==1?1:k==2?2:k==3?4:k==4?8:k==5?16:k==6?32:k==7?64:k==8?128:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate 37 en binario es `100101` y 33 es `100001` realmente lo que hacen es poner el tercer bit en 0 esto lo haces aplicando una mascara...Es decir haciendo un `&` con un numero conocido.

Es decir necesitas hacer la operacion `&` bit a bit con `111011` ... ahora como los numeros son más grandes dependiendo de la representación del hardware donde corra (16bits, 32 bits o 64bits) no sabes cuantos 1 tienes de relleno por lo tanto yo recomiento hacer la negacion de `4` que es `000000100` con los bits al reves....

```
 int c = 37;
 return c & (~4);
```

Comment: Es incluso más fácil usando los literales binarios de C++14: `int c = 0b100101; return c & 0b111011;`

Comment: Gracias, con tu solucion y la de eferion me quedo claro el asunto, es algo raro por que nunca habia usado estos operadores pero ahora  comprendo mejor.

Answer (score 0):

`return n & ~(1 << (k-1))` hace lo que buscas.

Te recomiendo que releas el enunciado del problema; en este tipo de operaciones, para `k` se suele considerar que su primer valor es 0, de modo que `(k-1)` quedaría simplemente como `k` (y el resultado para (n, k) = (37, 3) no sería 33, sino 37). En efecto, con lápiz y papel es más sencillo de entender.

Los operadores `<<` y `>>` desplazan un valor a izquierda o derecha (multiplican o dividen por 2). En este caso empezamos con un 1 y lo desplazamos a la izquierda `k-1` bits. Ya tenemos el 1 encima del bit de `n` que queremos modificar.

Como lo que queremos hacer es poner a 0 el bit, usamos `~` para negar el 1, poniéndo éste a 0 y el resto de bits a 1. Luego, al hacer el `&` con `n` dejaremos *pasar* los bits que corresponden con los 1 de nuestra máscara, dejando a 0 los que no.

Para que le pegues un repaso, esto (aunque algo más enrevesado) daría el mismo resultado:

`return ~(~n | (1 << (k-1)))`. ¿Entiendes por qué?

Answer (score 0):

return n & ~(1 << k);

La parte izda "n" es trivial

La parte derecha es la forma de poner un bit a 0 en C:

& ~(1 << k)